# DataTable date format change

Tags: vb.net

I am importing a date from a CSV file. The date column's format is dd/mm/yy.

How do I change the date format for a `DataTable` into the same format.

Here is my code:

```
datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ANALISEDATUM", GetType(Date)))
```

Comment: `DateTime` does not have any format. It's only formatted once you convert it to string

Comment: You have to parse the strings from the csv-file to `DateTime`. Therefore use `Date.Parse(dateString)`. If you get an exception you should show us the datestring.

Comment: Thank you Pikoh. Why can't I do the following :  data(i) = DBNull.Value.ToString("ddMMyy")

Comment: @Gideon: because `DBNull` is not a `DateTime`

Comment: Well, just analize it. You want to convert a null value to a string? why should that work?

Comment: I want to convert an empty date field in the CSV to a Null string.

Comment: Maybe a bit more clearer  : If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data(i))) Then
                                                data(i) = DBNull.Value.ToString
                                               End If